# How to atomically update multiple rows and select them, too?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to update multiple rows:

```
UPDATE tbl SET x = x + 5 WHERE x < 7;
```

Then, I would like to select the same rows as a resultset:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE (row fulfilled previous condition);
```

How would I do that?

Comment: Note to close fairies: Please make sure you close or merge this with an actually equivalent question that is not 10 years old.

Comment: Select the key values from the Where Condition into a temp table first, update, then select from the temp table joining on the updated table.

Comment: Which DBMS exactly  ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze In my case mySQL, but I'm trying to keep it somewhat generic.

Comment: In Postgres you could do a simple: `UPDATE tbl SET x = x + 5 WHERE x < 7 returning *`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - As I understood, OP needs old values after updating.

Comment: @OtoShavadze: that's not what I understand but anyway it's not applicable as mafu is using MySQL

Comment: @mafu, regarding your comment about closure, why would it matter if the answer is 10 years old, if it's an equivalent question and has correct answers? Some facts don't go out of style so quickly.

Answer (score 0):

This answer applies to mySQL, but it should be sufficiently universal to apply to other DBMS, too. It avoids additional rows, limiting or ugly hacks, is easy to extend, and does not lose performance without need.

```
START TRANSACTION;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp AS (
    SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE x < 7
);
UPDATE temp SET x = x + 5;
REPLACE INTO tbl SELECT * FROM temp;
SELECT * FROM temp;
COMMIT;
```

If you use this in PHP/PDO, you may need to select the right result set first. Error `HY000` is an indication for that.

```
$stmt = db -> prepare ($sql);
$stmt->execute ();
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++)
    $stmt->nextRowset ();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll ();
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL if you want to read the rows before updating them, you can do a locking read in a transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT ... FROM tbl WHERE x < 7 FOR UPDATE;
```

This acquires locks on the matching rows, exactly as if you had done an update. So no one else can get a lock on those rows until your transaction finishes.

You can then update the rows when you get around to it — but still in the same transaction.

```
UPDATE tbl SET x = x + 5 WHERE x < 7;

COMMIT;
```

If you want to update the rows first and then read them, you can do it in the other order:

```
START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE tbl SET x = x + 5 WHERE x < 7;

SELECT ... FROM tbl WHERE x < 7;

COMMIT;
```

But of course that could select a different set of rows, because x has changed. Any row where x >= 2 or greater before the UPDATE would have x >= 7 after the UDPATE, and therefore wouldn't be in the result of the subsequent SELECT.

All this syntax is standard SQL-99, so it should work in any compliant SQL implementation. But not all databases implement the standard in the same way, so refer to documentation for the brand you use.

E.g. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Other syntax like `RETURNING` and `OUTPUT` are not standard SQL as far as I know.

Answer (score -1):

FOR MS SQL Server, you need to use OUTPUT command [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/library/ms177564.aspx)

```
UPDATE tbl SET x = x + 5 
OUTPUT DELETED.*
WHERE x < 7
```

this will list all previous values

Answer (score -1):

postgres version

```
UPDATE tbl t1
SET    x = t1.x + 5
FROM  (SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE x < 7 FOR UPDATE) t2
WHERE  t1.x = t2.x
RETURNING t2.*
```